# Finding the element in <td></td> block

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to get the Status feild as shown in the screenshot  [Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCPqp.jpg)

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>STATUS</td>
        <td>TXN_SUCCESS</td>
    </tr>
<tbody>
```

How can I find this element in selenium. One approach is to use the Xpath but the xpath changes dynamically and hence it fails the next time I am trying to find this element?

The Xpath which I found is `/html/body/div[3]/center[2]/table/tbody/tr[10]/td[1]`

Can anyone please help me in this? Complete HTML is as below

```
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin-top: 10px">
    <div id="logo" style="float:left; margin-left: 20px">
        <a href="http://www.test.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/test.png" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="logo" style="float:right; margin-right: 20px">
        <a href="http://www.test.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="images/test_logo.png" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
        <center><h3>Response</h3></center>
        <p1> <font color="red">mid key not in property </font></p1>
        <center>
            <table border="1px; text-align: center;" class="tablesorter1"">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Parameter Name</th>
                <th>Parameter Value</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

                    <tr>
                        <td>BANKNAME</td>
                        <td>HDFC</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>BANKTXNID</td>
                        <td>3816913151570020</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>CURRENCY</td>
                        <td>INR</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>GATEWAYNAME</td>
                        <td>HDFC</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>MID</td>
                        <td>hybref63266728877901</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>ORDERID</td>
                        <td>8956552</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>PAYMENTMODE</td>
                        <td>CC</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>RESPCODE</td>
                        <td>01</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>RESPMSG</td>
                        <td>Txn Success</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>STATUS</td>
                        <td>TXN_SUCCESS</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>TXNAMOUNT</td>
                        <td>1.00</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>TXNDATE</td>
                        <td>2017-01-02 15:15:05.0</td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>TXNID</td>
                        <td>20170102111212800110166787500006704</td>
                    </tr>


                <tr>
                <td>Valid Checksum</td>
                <td>false</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share the complete html, what you posted is not enough to help you.

Comment: Never let a tool generate XPath for you. Write your XPath yourself, always. All tools will get it wrong, because all they give you is position-based XPath that depends on the exact document structure and breaks at the slightest difference. You want XPath based on the *value*, not on the position of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `xpath` to extract the status -

```
//tr/td[contains(text(),'STATUS')]/following-sibling::td
```

You can get the status like below code (Java code sample) and can manipulate as per your requirement -

```
    String status = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[contains(text(),'STATUS')]/following-sibling::td")).getText();
    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("TXN_SUCCESS"))
    {
        System.out.println("Transaction Success");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Transaction Failed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use for find to name `td`

`//td[text()='STATUS']`

for find value, use :

`//td[text()='STATUS']/../td[2]`